# Override MSI package logging level in WiX bootstrapper

Tags: wix, burn, wix3.10

I have a WiX boostrapper that install a bunch of MSI packages.

Well, some of them have lots of files, and the log created by boostrapper is huge.
From what I can tell the default logging level used by burn is set to "verbose"; so, I want to override this.
Using "MsiLogging" property doesn't seems to work.

So, you guys, do you know a way to accomplish my need?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an open feature request for this - [Request that Burn respect setting MsiLogging (like it does MSIFASTINSTALL)](https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/4554).